# CSS: Loading CSS without delay

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add padding on the logo carousel on the bottom half (so it always rests in the middle) of the screen on http://maginaire.concept9.ca/ .

However, when I click on the arrow to scroll through the logos, the padding only is applied after 1 second or so. Is there any way to prioritize the loading of this CSS snippet? Or should I edit something in the theme's default style.css?

In my custom.css for the WP theme I'm using I put:

```
.et_pb_fullwidth_portfolio .et_pb_carousel_group {width: 80%;}
.et_pb_fullwidth_portfolio .et_pb_carousel_group.active { padding-left:10% !important;}
.et_pb_fullwidth_portfolio .et_pb_carousel_group { padding-left:10% !important;}
```

Thanks a bunch!
Dan.

Comment: CSS is **always** applied instantly. There is no such thing as _"prioritize the loading of [the] CSS"_. A transition can affect the timing, but that isn't the case here. The problem is with your carousel, it probably overrides the padding when it scrolls to the next slide, and only removes it when the animation is complete.

Comment: I thought so too...in that case, how could I prevent the carousel from overriding it?

Comment: I haven't looked too hard into it to figure out what the actual problem is, but if you use `margin-left` instead of `padding-left`, it seems to fix it.

Comment: Is It resolved ? If no, then can you please tell in deep ? Cz I did nt get you.

Comment: @ChristianVarga thanks so much! margin-left worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin-left` instead of `padding-left` seems to have solved the animation transition 'bug' and achieved the result I needed.  Thanks @ChristianVarga!